# Is there a way to transfer ETH to block miner coinbase address using a transaction without a smart contract?

Tags: transactions, mining, ethers.js, transfer

Is there something similar to `block.coinbase.call{value: _ethAmountToCoinbase}(new bytes(0))` executing using Smart Contract? For example, from EthersJS:

```
const tx = signer.sendTransaction({
    to: "", // What to put here?
    value: ethers.utils.parseEther("1.0")
});
```

Comment: Welcome to the Ethereum Stack Exchange! It's an interesting question and what are you thinking of? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly, there is no way to use the "to" field of a transaction as `block.coinbase`.  The `to` field needs to be an address (or 0 for creating a contract).

But the miner will get your transaction fee.  So **instead of using `to` and `value`, you can simply increase your `gas price`**.  You have to be careful when you do that because you pay the `gas price` wei per unit of gas.  So you can set `value` 0, `to` as your own address, `gas limit` 21000, and `gas_price` 47619047619047.62 and that should send 1 ETH to the miner.  Try this with smaller numbers first, or on testnet, to be careful.

Comment: That's a great idea, I totally forgot about the constant gas amount of transferring! Thank you.